# Modifier key for not coming for shift key in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am firing the shift press event as follows:

```
KeyEventArgs x = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,0,Key.LeftShift);

Form1_Window_KeyDown(sender, x);
```

In the Form1_Window_KeyDown() function i am checking if the key pressed was of modifier type i.e. Shift,

```
Keyboard.Modifiers.ToString();
```

but it is not showing in the modifier list.

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to check if a key is pressed down:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check it like

```
(mask & Keyboard.Modifiers.Shift) == Keyboard.Modifiers.Shift
```

where `mask` is the value got from the system.